# how to iterate over sub directories dynamically

Tags: python, iteration

I have encounter this issue in multiple situations.

One use case here is, say I have a directory structure that can include unknown layers of sub-directories, and I want to get the total count of files under rootdir. What's the best way to iterate over this tree dynamically?

This is an example of the folder structure:

```
rootdir
   -> subdir1
     ->file1
          -> subsubdir1
                 -> file1
                 -> file2
          -> subsubdir2
                 -> file1
          -> subsubdir3
                 -> file1
                 -> subsubsubdir
                    -> file1
   -> subdir2
          -> subsubdirA
                 -> file1
                 -> file2
          -> subsubdirB
                 -> file1
                 -> file2
```

I'm getting the folder structure from an API call, not the file-system directly. Here is part of the api response. Suppose this is what I get from calling the rootdir, then I want to save the sub-folder id [1,2], then go into each sub-folder and iterate the same process of finding if sub-folder exist while keeping count of the files.

The response includes a total_count, which is the number of items (one sub-folder will be count as 1). So I need to keep track of the sub-folder id, and initiate a new api call for each sub-folder, to get the number of files in each sub-folder (and potentially subsubfolder), while keeping track of the total number of files. (Hope I explained this clearly. Feel free to comment if anything is unclear.)

```
{

"item_collection":{"total_count":3,
    "entries":[
    {"type":"folder","id":"1","sequence_id":"0","etag":"0"},
    {"type":"folder","id":"2","sequence_id":"0","etag":"0"},
    {"type":"file","id":"3","file_version"{"type":"file_version","id":"303835527128"},"sequence_id":"0","etag":"0",}
    ],
]}
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to keep track of each sub-folder and iterate over them dynamically. Any help is appreciated!

```
def total_file_count(client, folder_id):
    total_file_count = 0
    subfolder_ids = []
    folder = client.get_folder(folder_id=folder_id)
    item_count = folder['item_collection']['total_count']
    subfolder = True

    if item_count > 0:
        while subfolder:
            for i in folder['item_collection']['entries']:
                if i['type']=='folder':
                    subfolder_ids.append(i['id'])
                elif i['type']=='file':
                    total_file_count += 1

                subfolder = False if not subfolder_ids

    return total_file_count
```

Comment: The data posted does not seem to be fully nested. Could you post what a sample containing multiple subdirectories and files looks like?

Comment: To clarify, you are not working with a file-system directly, but instead working with a JSON representation of a file-system?

Comment: Your sample data indicates that you can simply get the number of entries. It does not indicate how subfolders and files within subfolders are represented. For example, does "total_count" give the total number of files (including folders)?

Comment: @MxyL thanks for the clarification. I have edited my post. Right, I'm working with JSON instead of the file-system directly. And the total_count is the # of item, so a sub-folder will be count as 1, but I want to go into each subfolder, and get the total number of files instead.

Comment: does each folder have a unique id in an absolute context or are the ids only unique relative to the parent directory?

Comment: Hi @DanTemkin each folder id is unique overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general approach using a while loop. The idea is you start with a list of folder ID's (which you supply as the root), and then from the entries you get, you would add any folders to search to that list. So while there are still folders to check, you would keep making requests and adding up file counts.

```
def get_file_count(client, folder_id):
  count = 0
  folders = [folder_id]
  while len(folders) > 0:
    id = folders.pop(0)
    data = client.get_folder(id)
    entries = data["item_collection"]["entries"]
    for entry in entries:
      if entry["type"] == "folder":
        folders.append(entry["id"])
      else:
        count += 1    
  return count
```

You may or may not be able to copy and paste it, but this is just for illustration purposes.

Ideally if there was an API that would give you all entries at the same time, that would be nice, but I can imagine a lot of use cases where that is not possible and so you will have to make requests again and again individually.

The solution is not optimized.

Comment: Just wanted to point out - I think this is an infinite loop because the length of the folders list will always be greater than 0.

Comment: @DanTemkin list of folders should become empty once there are no folders left to check.

Comment: oh ok! I see it now. It is a breadth first approach. I went for depth first.

Comment: Thank you @ThatUmbrellaGuy!  Sorry it took me a while to circle back to this.  Just wondering is there some algorithm that solves this type of problems I could look into?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get the use case entirely but this should work.
It will follow a sequence of folders until reaching a folder of only files
then backing out to the previous parent and working again. The recursion ends
when the function tries to backup past the root node.

Let me know if you you have problems implementing it, I was not able to debug without a full testcase.

I made a few assumptions based on your example,

1) The id's are simple integers and strictly cardinal.

2) The id of the first directory is 0 - this can be changed to some other integer

3) You are only looking for the file count.

I can try and rework my solution if some of these aren't true. But I hope this gets you started off on the right foot.

```
def iterdir(client, root, viewed=list(), steps=0, filecount=0):
    if root < 0:
        return filecount
    else:
        folder = client.get_folder(root)
        viewed.append(root)
        subdirs = [int(item['id']) for item in folder['item_collection']['entries'] if item['type'] == 'folder' and int(item['id']) not in viewed]
        if len(subdirs) == 0:
            iterdir(client=client, root=root - 1, steps = steps - 1, viewed=viewed, 
                    filecount=filecount+len([item for item in folder['item_collection']['entries'] if item['type'] == 'file']))       
        else:
            nfiles = len(folder['item_collection']['entries']) - len(subdirs)
            iterdir(client=client,
                    root=subdirs.pop(),
                    steps = steps + 1,
                    viewed=viewed, filecount = filecount + nfiles)
```